# Is there a package that allows customisation of the data components of a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, taxonomy

I've created a taxonomic table using the `MetabaR` package like this one (https://metabarfactory.github.io/metabaR/reference/ggtaxplot.html) and have been using `theme()` to edit aspects of it. However, when the figure is initially produced it has names that are angled, difficult to read, overlap, and run out of the boundary like this [My initial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5zZp.jpg).

I know that `theme()` works in layers and I have tried using `theme(text= element_blank())` to get rid of these names but this just clears- all text around my legends and not the taxa names.

If anyone knows of a package like `theme()` that gives me the same level of customization with data components to help edit this it would help me out a lot.

Cheers

Comment: I presume `metabaR::ggtaxplot` is a wrapper around `ggplot2`, which includes the `theme` function. if you look at the help at `?ggplot2::theme` you'll see there are many parameters to control different text elements. When you use `theme(text = ...` you are controlling all the text in the plot, in this case removing it all.

Comment: It was looking in ?ggplot2::theme where I found theme(text = .... I was hoping to clear all text so that I could then customise things the way that I wanted them. This cleared everything but the taxa names within the plot, which are the ones that are the most problematic. Within the themes help hile it indicates that it is for customising non-data components of the plots, which is what made me think I need to use a different package.

Comment: Looking at lines 174-177 here https://github.com/metabaRfactory/metabaR/blob/master/R/ggtaxplot.R, it looks like that text is added using a `geom_text` layer, which is separate from anything you can access in `theme`. To change that text's appearance, you could save your own version of the `ggtaxplot()` function with different text parameters in those lines.